# How to change color of background image via CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress, styling

I'm trying to change color of an image via CSS. The image is an element of my website's layout.
Here's screenshot showing the element: https://screenshots.firefox.com/xLCsVyZtSKLxFi9F/gameshunt.pl and here is an example post with the table - https://gameshunt.pl/promocje-na-gogu-2-05/

Its code looks like that:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th {
    background-image: url(/wp-content/plugins/table-sorter/images/bg.gif);
    cursor: pointer;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right center;
}
```

I tried `background-image: #fff, background image: #fff, url (wp-content/etc)` but nothing works. Does anyone have an idea how to change the color of this element? I can't just upload a different file because the color needs to be different only in dark mode.

Comment: background-image cannot be a color. it should be background

Comment: try this `background: #fff url(/wp-content/plugins/table-sorter/images/bg.gif);`

Comment: You can't. Background image is not an element, it's a property.

Comment: @Hammadtariq unfortunately it's not working properly. Check the screenshot: https://screenshots.firefox.com/n9dbsLUSvvbOtl1I/gameshunt.pl

Comment: @ kacper3355 `background: #fff url(/wp-content/plugins/table-sorter/images/bg.gif) no-repeat;`

Answer (score -1):

You could try making the arrows using CSS:

```css
div {
  background: grey;
  padding: 5px;
}

.sort:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
}

.sort:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 3px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.white:before {
  border-bottom: 5px solid white;
}

.white:after {
  border-top: 5px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="sort"></div>
<div class="sort white"></div>
```